# Indent the variable definition after an equation

Tags: equations, formatting

I would like to indent the definition of the variables used in the equation like below:

```
a = b + c

where,
    a = the variable a
    b = the variable b
    c = the variable c
```

I have tried doing as shown below, but it does not work:

```
\begin{frame}
    \[ a = b + c \]
    \begin{small}
        where, \\
        \indent a = the variable a\\
        \indent b = the variable b\\
        \indent c = the variable c
    \end{small}
\end{frame}
```

Please let me know the correct way to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\parindent` is `0pt` by default in `beamer`, so `\indent` will do nothing. Better use another approach anyway

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\[ a = b + c \]
where
\begin{tabular}[t]{r@{}l}
$a={}$ & the variable a\\
$b={}$ & the variable b\\
$c={}$ & the variable c
\end{tabular}

or
$\begin{aligned}[t]
a&=\text{the variable a}\\
b&=\text{the variable b}\\
c&=\text{the variable c}
\end{aligned}$

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\begin{small}...\end{small}` works because of a quirk of how `\begin` and `\end` are defined.